# PHP - How do I run mysql query in while loop?

Tags: php, mysql

My original query was to select data from phpadmin table and display into table.

```
$sql="select * from table";
$result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

while($myrow=MySQL_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    extract($myrow);
    echo "<td align='left' bgcolor='$bgclr'>".$myrow[0]."</td>";    
    echo "<td align='left' bgcolor='$bgclr'>".$myrow[1]."</td>";    
    echo "<td align='left' bgcolor='$bgclr'>".$myrow[2]."</td>";    
    echo "<td align='left' bgcolor='$bgclr'>".$myrow[3]."</td>";    
}
```

Then I need to display another column using value of `$myrow[0]` to execute another query to get the value.

```
$sql="select * from table";
$result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

while($myrow=MySQL_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    extract($myrow);

    $id = $myrow[0];
    $sql="select amount from table2 where id like '%$id%'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    echo "<td align='left' bgcolor='$bgclr'>".$myrow[0]."</td>";    
    echo "<td align='left' bgcolor='$bgclr'>".$myrow[1]."</td>";    
    echo "<td align='left' bgcolor='$bgclr'>".$myrow[2]."</td>";    
    echo "<td align='left' bgcolor='$bgclr'>".$myrow[3]."</td>";    

    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {

            echo "<td align='left' bgcolor='$bgclr'>".$row[0]."</td>";echo "</tr>";
        }   
    }
```

And my page became blank. And the error was at

> $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

Is it the correct method or how should I do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I mix MySQL APIs in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17498216/can-i-mix-mysql-apis-in-php)

Comment: usually you're better off using a join statement, so that you wouldn't need to repeat the query every iteration

Comment: you mix mysql and mysqli

Comment: `like` with id makes no sence

Comment: Use prepared Statements to prevent SQL injection

Comment: " phpadmin table" Phpmyadmin  is not a database, its a php script, just like yours

Comment: Always post the error message if you get an error

Comment: It would be much better if you combined both these SQL statements into 1 query.

Comment: I'm not able to combine queries because I'm selecting data from different tables with different connections.

Comment: Running iterated queries based on an earlier query's result set is evidence of poor database interaction.  You and all researchers should ignore the accepted answer and perform a single query using a JOIN of the two tables.  If your question was clearer, I could write the appropriate query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You overwrite variable `$result` while executing query inside the loop here:

```
$sql="select amount from table2 where id like '%$id%'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

Change variable name `$result` inside the loop and code will be like:

```
$sql="select amount from table2 where id like '%$id%'";
$result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

Also update it here:

```
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result2)) {

            echo "<td align='left' bgcolor='$bgclr'>".$row[0]."</td>";echo "</tr>";
        }   
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Mate !!! It was just so simple and I couldn't see my mistake !!! U saved my day !!!

Comment: Also don't forget to check the comments above about prepared statements!